# Except statement won't return back to For loop Python tweepy

Tags: python, for-loop, twitter, connection, tweepy

I have the following code. For a twitter account with more than 75k followers, I always get this error:

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

That's why I have added the except block in my code as listed in
[Getting back to back error using "wait_on_rate_limit" parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914315/getting-back-to-back-error-using-wait-on-rate-limit-parameter/63579276#63579276)

For any account with more than 75k followers, I will get that error, it will meet the except clause, and then ideally it should 'continue' back into the loop and fetch the remaining followers. But it wont, at that point it just goes out of the loop and it stops.
I don't understand what am I missing?

My code:

```
for entity in entities:
    try:
        c = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=entity,count=5000)
        for pages in c.pages():
            id.append(pages)
            et.append(entity)
            d = {'follower_id': id[i], 'name': et[i]}
            df_temp=pd.DataFrame(d)
            df = df.append(df_temp)
            print('Loop NUmber:',i)
            i=i+1
            print(df.shape)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
        time.sleep(60 * backoff_counter)
        backoff_counter += 1
        continue
```

Please tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but may help narrow down the problem.

Try this code. It stores the iterators in lists so they (hopefully) end. It also keeps count for the entities and pages.

```
i=0
id = []
et = []
backoff_counter = 1
entCtr = 0
while True:
    try:
        lstEntities = list(entities)  # lock entity list
        print('Entity Length', len(lstEntities))
        for entity in lstEntities:
            entCtr += 1
            print('entCtr', entCtr)
            c = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=entity,count=5000)
            lstPages = list(c.pages())  # freeze here ?
            print('entCtr', entCtr, 'Page Length', len(lstPages))
            i = 0
            for pages in lstPages:
                id.append(pages)
                et.append(entity)
                d = {'follower_id': id[i], 'name': et[i]}
                df_temp=pd.DataFrame(d)
                df = df.append(df_temp)
                print('Page Loop Number:',i)
                i=i+1
                print(df.shape)
        break
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
        time.sleep(60 * backoff_counter)
        backoff_counter += 1
        continue
```

Comment: When I try to run this, it goes inside the first For loop but it does not go inside the second For loop. Not able to understand why.

Comment: Please update your post with the new code and the output. My guess is that `c.Pages()` never ends.

Comment: Hi, I changed my code from a While loop to a For loop. Now the problem is that it just comes out of the loop even after I have set an except clause to meet the error. Please advise, if you can.